# Problems about snmpd configuration on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, snmpd

I have the following questions about the configuration of snmpd service on Ubuntu server 16.04 LTS:

**Question 1:**

In the `/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf`, there is a snippet of comment:

```
###############################################################################
#
#  SNMPv3 AUTHENTICATION
#
#  Note that these particular settings don't actually belong here.
#  They should be copied to the file /var/lib/snmp/snmpd.conf
#     and the passwords changed, before being uncommented in that file *only*.
#  Then restart the agent
```

Note the `They should be copied to the file /var/lib/snmp/snmpd.conf` part.

But in the `/var/lib/snmp/snmpd.conf`, there's another snippet of comment:

```
############################################################################
# STOP STOP STOP STOP STOP STOP STOP STOP STOP 
#
#          **** DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE ****
#
# STOP STOP STOP STOP STOP STOP STOP STOP STOP 
############################################################################
```

So should I create user in `/var/lib/snmp/snmpd.conf` or not?

**Question 2:**

Should the password part of `createUser` be cleartext or digest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was frustrating for me too and I ran into a few bumps on the road but I think I have deciphered it now.

Issuing ie. the statement `createUser mysnmpuser SHA "mystrongpassword" AES` in `/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf` and restarting the snmpd service will generate configuration for mysnmpuser in `/var/lib/snmp/snmpd.conf`.

After the service restart the password in `/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf` won't be used again. Hence the recommendation to remove it from the configuration file.

- `SHA` - Means that the password will be hashed using SHA when authenticating.
- `AES` - Means that the payload of each packet will be encrypted using AES (using mystrongpassword as key).

You can test your configuration by issuing this command:

`snmpwalk -v3 -l authPriv -u mysnmpuser -a SHA -A mystrongpassword -x AES -X mystrongpassword localhost`

Please also note that you then also need to add the statement `rouser mysnmpuser` * (or whatever permission you want to assign to the user) further down in `/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf`.

Hope that helps someone else!